# Don't understand why an IndentationError occurs in this code that converts int to float

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I keep getting the `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` error when trying to build an HTML scraper that can look for discounts in price. But when converting `int` to `float`.

```
converted_price = float(price[0:5])
if(converted_price < 40.99):
        send_mail()
    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())
    if(converted_price > 40.99):
        send_mail()
```

I get the error message. What am I doing wrong?

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/Toilettendeckel-Absenkautomatik-Antibakterieller-Urea-Duroplast-Edelstahlscharnier/dp/B0881PKQ2H/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AKQL6N75FLK4O&pd_rd_w=hTIPC&pf_rd_p=d051a36d-9331-41c8-9203-e7d634b1ee23&pf_rd_r=3TS01EKWNMYSRC1147X1&pd_rd_r=d950f9b1-8e9a-4913-b266-9b7a36ad21f5&pd_rd_wg=GLsoO&ref_=pd_gw_unk'

headers = {"User-agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}

def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_saleprice").get_text
    converted_price = float(price[0:5])

if(converted_price < 40.99):
        send_mail()

    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())

    if(converted_price > 40.99):
        send_mail()


def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('madbro88a@gmail.com', 'gsplmdqkaavnuxnb')

    subject = 'Price fell down!'
    body = 'https://www.amazon.de/Toilettendeckel-Absenkautomatik-Antibakterieller-Urea-Duroplast-Edelstahlscharnier/dp/B0881PKQ2H/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AKQL6N75FLK4O&pd_rd_w=hTIPC&pf_rd_p=d051a36d-9331-41c8-9203-e7d634b1ee23&pf_rd_r=3TS01EKWNMYSRC1147X1&pd_rd_r=d950f9b1-8e9a-4913-b266-9b7a36ad21f5&pd_rd_wg=GLsoO&ref_=pd_gw_unk'

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
        'mail1',
        'mail2',
        msg
    )
    print('Email has been sent!')

    server.quit()


price_check()
```

Comment: Why did you indent `send_mail()` more than `print(converted_price)`?

Comment: Honestly i'm just following this guy's tutorial. I'm not really sure what i'm doing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&list=WL&index=1&ab_channel=DevEd

Comment: @mkrieger1: Actually, I think that `if(converted_price < 40.99):` is indented less than `converted_price = ...`

Comment: Please find the correct indentation for your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: BTW, `if` is not a function, so drop the parentheses. `if(converted_price < 40.99):` should be `if converted_price < 40.99:`.

Comment: @Matthias The parentheses are fine, though unnecessary. Conventionally, there would be a space between `if` and the first `(`, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code presentations in the question contradict each other.

Comment: Which code box is showing the actual code?

Answer (score 1):

The source of the error is in this section:

```
if(converted_price < 40.99):
        send_mail()
```

In Python after any line that requires an indentation such as an `if`, `while`, `def`, etc you must indent the following line by <strike>*one* tab, or the equivalent using spaces.</strike> at least one space. All subsequent lines in an indented block should be indented to the same level. Convention is to use 4 spaces (thanks [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1)).  Whitespace is very important in Python.

In your example you have indented the line `send_mail()` *two* tabs deeper than the `if` statement. If you reduce the indentation of `send_mail()` by one the compiler error is resolved.

The corrected code should be:

```
if(converted_price < 40.99):
    send_mail()
```

Note that in your full code you have the following block indented one too little:

```
if(converted_price < 40.99):
        send_mail()

    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())

    if(converted_price > 40.99):
        send_mail()
```

This whole block needs to be indented to be within the `def check_price():` function.

Comment: "...must indent by one tab" – any amount of whitespace works, it just needs to be the same in every line of an indented block. The convention is to use 4 spaces and *no* tabs.

Comment: Right you are. I've corrected myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in *Full code* `if(converted_price < 40.99):`
is part of the `check_price()` function, so you have to indent it.